# What are the /dev/bpf* files? And can I delete them?

Tags: mac, folders

I have about 250 /dev/bpf* files in my /dev dir. What are they for and can I delete them?

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason for messing around in `/dev`, I'd highly recommend you stay out of the `/dev` directory. In Terminal,  have a look at `man bpf`, they are Berkeley Packet Filter character special devices.

Comment: @user3439894 I understand the /dev directory contains device files and is basically the link between the computer and actual devices, but this is more about understanding why there are so many of these bpf* files and where they came from. I don't necessarily need to mess with them, but I would like to understand them a little more.

Comment: From googling it seems they were created by wireshark, but why so many of them? And is it gonna stop making them, or will it continually keep making more and more?

Comment: Then I'd start with the man page for `bpf`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think to "man bpf"... reading it now.